# Is there a way to limit or prioritize how much processing power an OpenCL application can use?

Tags: macos, opencl, gpu

First, I'm not even an OpenCL newbie-- I know what it is but I haven't so much as written one line of code.  However, I have looked through some OpenCL on a very simple, open-source project and understanding the structure of the code seems to be pretty easy since it's very C like and I am a C/Obj-C developer.

The mentioned open sourced project has one problem.  It wants to run on your OS X machine with full GPU priority.  This means that when I run the application my Mac remains functional, but at a very degraded state.

Is there some way that I can easily modify the application and set some flag to lower that applications GPU priority?

I may not know the OpenCL API, but if there is a simple function call or two that I can place in the applications initialization function, I can probably fix this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html) is probably the call used in that application to launch an OpenCL kernel on the GPU device. You can try adjusting the values of work_dim, global_work_size and local_work_size that are passed into this method and see if responsiveness improves. Note that the kernel may stop functioning if the person who wrote it has specified or assumed these sizes. In that case, you will need to edit the kernel to make this happen.

You can use the [OpenGL extension viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/) to check the allowed range of values on each of these parameters for your hardware setup.